What OCR tools can recognize text by rows instead of columns?
What free OCR tools for Windows that satisfies these?

Automatically add layer on the PDF files (so that the non OCRed file can be saved as an OCRed one)
Can recognize text by rows instead of columns:


No 3rd party project for Tesseract seems to satisfies (1), and (2) disqualifies most PDF software with built-in OCR feature like PDF-XChange Viewer.

Related: How to OCR tables of contents to proper outputs?
